# How to enable the close icon(React Icons) within the button

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-design, material-ui, react-icons

I have multiple button on the screen , I want that user either click this button to route to the new item or user could have close this , for that i have given the close icon within the button so that user can close that if they want , but when i am trying to give onclick function to the icon within the button it does not work

how could i do that ???

Here is the demo code

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rbkr8

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it with a div onClick like this?

```
const doSomething = () => {
  alert('click here');
}

<div onClick={doSomething}>
      <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
</div>
```

Comment: still unable to close when i clicked the close icon :(

Comment: @Bilawal im unable to see the close icon in the demo? does the console returns any error?

Comment: here is the updated one 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rbkr8
unfortunately that also doesnt work !!